# Problema com subtração em Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

Meu professor mandou esse código simples em C, para transformá-lo em Assembly:

```
int num1, num2, resultado;
printf("Digite o primeiro numero: \n");
scanf("%d", &num1);
printf("Digite o segundo numero: \n");
scanf("%d", &num2);
resultado = num1 - num2;
printf("O resultado e: %d\n", resultado);
```

Até agora eu fiz isso:

```
    .data
str1:    .asciiz "\nnumero 1 "
str2:    .asciiz "\nnumero 2 "
str3:    .asciiz "\nResultado: "

       .text
   .globl main
   
main:

   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, str1
   syscall
  
   li $v0, 5
   la $t1, ($t2)
   syscall
  
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, str2
   syscall
 
   li $v0, 5
   la $s1, ($s2)
   syscall

   sub $a1, $t1, $s1
  
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, str3
   syscall
  
   li $v0, 1
   move $a0, $a1
   syscall
```

Mas o resultado ta dando errado (ex: 10 - 5 = 0). Como corrigir isso?

Comment: Olá. Olha, só pra te dar um feedback, a pergunta não está mal feita não, e a meu ver demonstra algum esforço. Mas está muito específica para o seu problema, então não me parece que esteja servindo para ajudar outras pessoas, que é o propósito do site. Vou votar para fechar mas aguardamos melhoria dela para reabertura e responder um questionamento mais "geral". Com isso até o título da pergunta pode ser melhorado, para que sirva melhor em buscas feitas por outros usuários.

Comment: Discordo de seu argumento. Minha dúvida pode inclusive ser a dúvida outras pessoas, que estão tendo o mesmo problema, já que se trata de uma operação simples de subtração.

Comment: Posso ter me enganado mesmo. Não conheço quase nada de assembly, então fiz uma dedução meio à base da suposição. Também parece que ninguém mais concordou comigo até agora. Vou ficar de olho e se for o caso até retiro o voto e deixo meu +1 para a pergunta.